# What is the differences of util.inherits, prototype and Object.setPrototypeOf? (JavaScript/Node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, oop, inheritance, ecmascript-6

How can I differentiate this codes? I know I can also use Class obj1 inherits obj2 but I just want the comparison of the codes below so I can decide what to use depending on difference circumstances.

```
util.inherits(obj1, obj2);
```

vs

```
obj1.__proto__ = obj2;
```

vs

```
Object.setPrototypeOf(obj1, obj2);
```

Comment: I've never seen the first type. Where did you learn it?

Comment: util is a node.js library. I forgot to write that this question is for nodejs.

Comment: You could probably look up the source code, I'll bet it just does one of the other methods.

Comment: Actually you should use neither of them in ES6 - as you mentioned `class obj1 extends obj2` is the proper way